# Angular Scenario Test Runner displays page but assertions fail

Tags: django, testing, angularjs, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm trying to use Angular's [Scenario Test Runner](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) with my Django 1.4.4 webapp.

**Setup**: I copied the scenario test runner files over from a fresh pull of the angular phonecat tutorial project (Mar 2013, 9a55c8).  I put the test dir alongside the other static assets like js, css, etc*. I am using Angular for some binding, but not routing.

**Problem**: When I run the e2e runner and issue `browser().navigateTo('../../../<myapp>');` I can see the page from my app load (in the bottom section of the test runner screen), but it's as if the tester cannot see it. The `browser().location()` or `.path()` value is empty in my test code. And if I try to assert anything about elements on that page, those elements are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there was actually nothing wrong with the setup. What led me to believe there was were observations based on two misunderstandings of the API. In case someone has similar issues, take note that:

1. Patterns such as `element(selector)` return future objects which appear empty until they have been executed. Because they looked empty I believed they had not matched. Using them with expectations as demonstrated in the examples works, such as:
   `expect(element('title').text()).toMatch('.*Home Page.*');`
2. The `browser().location()` uses the [$location service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location), which is by default configured to use Hashbang URLs (e.g., `http://foo.com/#!/bar?param=val#hash`). Since I'm using traditional URLs (without the hash) the path and URL were empty. Using `browser().window().href()` achieved the desired goal.